# How to generate cross-toolchain for the platform with Yocto?

Tags: yocto, toolchain

I am relatively new to Yocto.

I have a Yocto project which builds properly an image for sm2s-imx8mp machine. `helloworld` application is built as part of the image. From the logs I see that `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc` cross compiler was used to compile `helloworld`.

Now I have to use the toolchain (which was used by Yocto to compile the `helloworld`) also outside the Yocto to compile other apps.

The question is: what is the correct way to obtain the toolchain package for the sm2s-imx8mp machine with Yocto?

Does Yocto have something like `bitbake build_toolchain` command to obtain the toolchain?

Comment: The Standard SDK provides a cross-development toolchain and libraries tailored to the contents of a specific image. USe this command bitbake myimage -c populate_sdk. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#id1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment suggested, to build SDK from Yocto, you should use:

```
bitbake image_name -c populate_sdk
```

and after build is completed, you will find your SDK in: `build/tmp/deploy/sdk`

Comment: Thanks, yes, this works. Just would like to add, that in order to add required libraries and/or packages to the generated toolchain, variable TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK should be appended with the corresponding list of recipes.